# How can I remove a font dowloaded with @font-face from the browser cache?

Tags: css, font-face

Some time ago I asked this question and none of the answers solved my problem. My clients are complaining so I'm gonna try once again:

I published a new release of my webapp using @font-face with a limited version of "Droid Sans" (no Latin characters). The font files are hosted on my server. A week later I changed the font with a full version because most of my customers use Spanish language. The new customers get the new full font with no problem, but the customers who accessed first time with the limited font published don't get the special characters any more.

I guess the old font is cached somewhere in the browser, but I haven't been able to remove it.

I've tried to change the font name and the css definition for the browser to download again... nothing is working. Anyone knows how to fix this?

This is my css definition:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Droid';
src: url(/files/DroidSans.eot);
src: url(/files/DroidSans.eot?iefix) format('eot'),
     url(/files/DroidSans.woff) format('woff'),
     url(/files/DroidSans.ttf) format('truetype'),
     url(/files/DroidSans.svg#webfontw7zqO19G) format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'DroidBold';
src: url(/files/DroidSansBold.eot);
src: url(/files/DroidSansBold.eot?iefix) format('eot'),
     url(/files/DroidSansBold.woff) format('woff'),
     url(/files/DroidSansBold.ttf) format('truetype'),
     url(/files/DroidSansBold.svg#webfontSOhoM6aS) format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

body, a, p, div, span, li, td, th, caption {
  font-family: Droid, Optima, Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
  line-height: 14pt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said that you *"tried to change the font name and the css definition"*.  I would also try to change the font name AND resave the font file names, so

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'DroidBoldNEW';
src: url(/files/DroidSansBoldNEW.eot);
src: url(/files/DroidSansBoldNEW.eot?iefix) format('eot'),
     url(/files/DroidSansBoldNEW.woff) format('woff'),
     url(/files/DroidSansBoldNEW.ttf) format('truetype'),
     url(/files/DroidSansBoldNEW.svg#webfontSOhoM6aS) format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

See if that works.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I did, but I got the same results. Everyone says it should work but it doesn't.